# VSTO Outlook: Show custom taskpane only in the compose, reply and forward windows

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created a custom taskpane to show custom messages to the user. Now, I would like to show this taskpane only in compose, reply and forward windows. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `MailItem.Sent` property is false before displaying your task pane.

Comment: So MailItem.Sent = False means that i am in the compose, reply and forward windows?

Comment: That is correct. `MailItem.Sent == false` means it is a draft item.